# Sum over Sum in SQL server ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

*here is the [sqlonline](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/87752)*

There is a band.

Each member plays an instrument.

each instrument costs X$

I would like to create a report  : how much each member *'costs'* to the band manager.

```
create table #Inst(id int, name nvarchar(max) , price int )
insert into  #Inst values  (1,'guitar',20), 
                           (2,'bass',10),
                           (3,'drums',30),
                           (4,'piano',40) 
  
  create table #Players(id int, name nvarchar(max) , instId int )
  insert into  #Players values (1,'john',1), 
                               (2,'john',4),
                               (3,'paul',2),
                               (4,'paul',2),
                               (5,'george',1),
                               (6,'ringo',3)
```

What have I tried ?

```
select name , totalCostToTheband=   
              (select sum(price) from #inst i where i.id= #players.instId ) 
from #players
```

but this yields duplicate names :

[image]

I want to see 4 records which summarize each name's costs.

**p.s. :**
*I could  have created a sum() over the whole query  , but i want to know if there is a better , elegant solution.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current schema you should do

```
SELECT 
    p.name , 
    sum(price) as totalCostToTheband
FROM
    #players p 
    INNER JOIN #inst i ON i.id = p.instId
GROUP BY
    p.name
```

---

But when you have many-to-many relations you normally do a middle table with the links

```
create table #Inst(id int, name nvarchar(max) , price int )
create table #Players(id int, name nvarchar(max) )
create table #instplayer(id int, inst_id, player_id )
```

This saves from duplicating the players inside the `#players` table, and also allows for players with the same name to be in the same band ;)

Read http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/ for more info

Comment: Should be `p.name` after SELECT and GROUP BY.

Comment: I know I should have created a map table . but the question was just for catching the concept. ( sum over sum)

Comment: @royi, ok .. i just put it there for completeness of the answer (*for any interested eyes in the future*).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your query by adding a group by, like this:

```
select p.name
,   (select sum(price) from #inst i where i.id= p.instId ) as totalCostToTheband
from #players p
group by p.name
```

However, a better approach would be to use a join:

```
select p.name, sum(i.price) as totalCostToTheband
from #players p
join #inst i on i.id=p.instId
group by p.name
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "#players.instId" could not be bound.

Comment: also the first : Column '#players.instId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.